# Extract Event Time from Windows Log using PS

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I am executing this powershell script to check the Windows Event Log viewer for a speficic job result.

It's working, however I'm stuck on one part...
I'm trying to do is pull the last/most recent event time/date and add it to the exit code.

```
"Task Completed Successfully at **_______**"
```

I have looked around a bit and tried a few different approaches without success... not the best at PS, can someone assist?

```
Param(
    [string]$Task,
    [string]$PastMinutes
)

$StartAt = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$PastMinutes)
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$action = (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational"; id=102; StartTime=$StartAt} | 
    Where-Object {($_.Message -like $Task) -and ($_.Message -like "Task Scheduler Successfully Finished*")})

if ($action.count -ne "0") {
    Write-Host "OK: "$Task" Task Completed Successfully at _______!"
    Exit 0
} else {
    Write-Host "CRITICAL: "$Task" Task Failed to Complete!"
    Exit 2
}
```

Comment: Hi Roland77 - is there a reason you aren't just pulling the info off the task directly? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/12/use-powershell-to-show-results-of-scheduled-tasks/

Comment: Let me check... im not sure if the result changes from 0 if the task is already running or gets hung...

Comment: It’s better if we drill down and pull from events.. possible to pull date from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really do hate condensing code in ultralong lines until it is nearly unreadable.

As `$action(s)` has a `.TimeCreated` property, I'd use that.

This may work:

```
Param(
    [string]$Task,
    [string]$PastMinutes
)

$StartAt = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$PastMinutes)
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$FilterHashTable = @{
    logname   = "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational"
    id        = 102
    StartTime = $StartAt
}

$actions = (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHashTable | 
    Where-Object {($_.Message -like $Task) -and 
                  ($_.Message -like "Task Scheduler Successfully Finished*")})

## set negative result hopefully overwritten by action
$Result = "CRITICAL: {0} Task Failed to Complete!" -F $Task

if ($actions){
    ForEach($action in $actions){
        $Result = "OK: {0} Task Completed Successfully at {1}" -F $Task,$action.TimeCreated
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. Had to edit it a bit - but definitely did the trick. 

I didn't know PS code could be formatted like that otherwise I would have done it much sooner. Long lines are definitely hard on the eyes and mind.